# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No serializer for 'SignIn'

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying to serialize a json response using built_value.
I have created this classes:
1.- SigIn class.
2.- SigninDataSource.
3.- Serializer.

The service is working well and i get that response:

```
{"status": 200, 
 "user_id": "****", 
 "id_token": "****", 
 "refresh_token": "****", 
 "expires_in": 3600 }
```

The problem is when I try to serialize the response.body.

when I try to do that I get this error:

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No serializer for 'SignIn'

This is the code that I am using:
1.- SignIn

```
abstract class SignIn implements Built<SignIn, SignInBuilder>{
 static Serializer<SignIn> get serializer => _$signInSerializer;
 @nullable
 int get status;

 @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'user_id')
 String get userId;

 @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'id_token')
 String get idToken;

 @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'refresh_token')
 String get refreshToken;

 SignIn._();

 factory SignIn([updates(SignInBuilder b)]) = _$SignIn;

 static SignIn fromJson(String jsonString) {
  return serializers.deserializeWith(SignIn.serializer,
  json.decode(jsonString));
 }
}
```

2.- Serializer
part 'serializers.g.dart';

```
@SerializersFor(const [SignIn,])

final Serializers serializers = 
(_$serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();
```

3.- SigninDataSource

```
class SigninDataSource {

Future<SignIn> signIn ({
 String email = '***@hotmail.com',
 String apiKey = '****',
 String password = '****',
}) async {
 var url = "https://api-dev.com/signin";
 var body = json.decode('{"email": "$email", "password": 
          "$password"}');
 http.post(url, body: json.encode(body),
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": apiKey,
      "content-type" : "application/json",})
    .then((response) {
  print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response body: ${response.body}");

  return SignIn.fromJson(response.body);

  }
 );
}
}
```

I would like that someone can help with this problem.

Comment: I found the problem, it was related with s serializers library i was using one from dart , instead that I had to use one that I created in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `Bad state` error which occurs when Flutter is expecting an element or object but it's inaccessible for some reason. The error points out that there's no Serializer for the object SignIn. See if the method that you're calling is existing in that package.

Common causes of this issue is if you're importing two packages with similar classes inside. If that's the case, then you might need to assign names to your package imports.

i.e.

```dart
import 'package:package_name1/apple.dart' as package1;
import 'package:package_name2/banana.dart' as package2;
```